# Multiple Bodies in a POST operation

Tags: postman

I have the following question, I want to make a request for a POST, I have 13 different Body's in environment variables, how can I put all 13 at the same time in Postman to execute?  Is there any way?

This is my code:
Some Bodies:

```
{ "et": "conta", "na": "List", "T": "list", "OPT": [ "TL-1", "TL-2" ], "DBY": "names user", "iM": false }

{ "et": "conta", "na": "Integer", "T": "integer", "DBY": "namesUser", "iM": false }

{ "et": "conta", "na": "MultiSelectList", "T": "multiSelect", "opt": [ "L1", "L2", "L3" ], "DBY": "names user", "iM": true }
```

What I am doing but I get error 400:

```
[
    {{List}},
    {{Integer}}
]
```

So I would like to know if there is any way to be able to execute the 13 Body's placing them all at the same time

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your code/ requests. Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I edit it above to make it clearer.

Comment: You should use *json arrays*

Comment: All bodies are stored in the same environment variable?

Comment: No, @Christian Baumann, they are different variables, one for each Body.

Comment: Do you want to send 13 requests at the very same time, each using different bodies? Or you want to send 1 request with the data from all 13 variables as one body?

Comment: I would like to send all 13 at the same time, as if it were a JSON, if possible, if it is not, I will continue to do it as I have done so far, one variable at a time

Comment: What is the API your working against? Any documentation available?

Comment: I wish I could pass it to you, but it's private :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json arrays (https://restfulapi.net/json-array/) should be used for this

```
    [
        { 
             "et": "conta", 
             "na": "List", 
             "T": "list", 
             "OPT": [ 
                 "TL-1", 
                 "TL-2" 
             ], 
             "DBY": "names user", 
             "iM": false 
        },
        {
             (second array)
        },
        .
        .
        .
        {
             (thirteenth array)
        }
    ]
```

Good to know: you can use this tool to verify your json; https://jsonlint.com/

Whether or not this results in a status 400 error depends on the implementation of the web api's post method (and you mentioned this happens). In .NET, the received json should be converted to a `List<T>` instead of type `T`.

- If you posting to your own api, try changing it according to: https://forums.asp.net/t/2098779.aspx?How+to+change+WEB+API+to+accept+a+JSON+Array+for+multiple+entries+
- If it's an external api, sending an array won't work. You have to send the data sequentially, but there are some tips and tricks preventing you from doing this manually in Postman: [How to Send multiple request concurrently/Sequentially in postman with different set of values for each request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460417/how-to-send-multiple-request-concurrently-sequentially-in-postman-with-different)

Comment: I already tried something like this, but I still have Status Code: 400 Bad Request, I think rather that the EndPoint does not allow me to do this type of action.

Comment: Can you send simpler json `{ "et": "conta", "na": "List", "T": "list", "OPT": [ "TL-1", "TL-2" ], "DBY": "names user", "iM": false }` to this endpoint? Or does it also result in status 400?

Comment: With only one it works, but when I put 2 or more, it gives me the error 400

Comment: Hmm weird. And you verified it's valid json?

Comment: Sure, I validated them and if they are valid, however I don't know if it has to do with the POST, maybe it doesn't allow it, I don't know ...

Comment: Error 400 tells that the server was unable to process your request. Where are you sending the json to, and are you sure it can de deserialized properly?

Comment: That's the part that I don't know, that's why I say it has to be the POST method that I have.

Comment: Yes the post method doesn't support this syntax. I've sent some links with ways to implement that.

Comment: I appreciate it @Casper Dijkstra, I will review them.